# Is this a bounded operator on $\ell^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces

Let $\alpha \ge 0$. Consider a function $T: \ell^2(\mathbb N) \rightarrow \mathbb C^\infty$ given by a following formula:
$${(Tx)}_n = \frac {1}{n^\alpha} \sum_{k \ne n} \frac{x_k}{|n - k|}.$$

Clearly, this is a linear mapping. I have shown that if $\alpha > \frac 1 2$ then $\mathrm{im}\ T \subset \ell^2$ and this function is a bounded operator on $\ell^2$ (in this case, matrix of this operator is square-summable). And if $\alpha = 0$ then I have shown that $T \left(x_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt k \log k},k \ge 2\right) \notin \ell^2$.

I have some problems with $\alpha \in (0, \frac 1 2]$ (I wanted to apply Schur test but I couldn't find any acceptable sequences). Could someone provide me with any useful information on this problem?

Comment: have you tried cauchy-schwarts with $x^k$ and $\frac{1}{|k-n|}$?

Comment: @LiterallyanOrange yes I tried and $\|{(Tx)}_n\| \le \frac 1 {n^\alpha} \cdot \frac{ 2 \pi}{\sqrt 6} \cdot {\|x\|}_{\ell^2}$. It's not very informative...